# Installing xpage extension library does not load any extension library controls in browser

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am installing the extension library in one of my local machine,I have previously also installed extension library in another machine and that is working fine,but now in another machine all settings and process is same, To test whether the extension library is installed or not I have created a test page and added layout control and according from extension library to the page and executed the page from the browser,It is not giving any error and prints the values which i have given in the layout.but layout is not visible.
   In short the controls from the extension library are not visible when executed the page in browser,
   I have Verified the extension library installed on designer as below image.
[image: installed on designer]

I have Verified the extension library installed on server as below image.

[image: server response]

So in server responses the state is LAZY,bit confused here whether the library is loaded on server properly or not.Or i have to do all the process again to get library started.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Edit 1: I forgot to mention that I am using domino designer 9 and notes 9,the domino server version is 8.5,Is there any issues with version?

Edit 2:Now I have converted domino server, domino designer,notes client to version 8.5,Currently I have every thing of same version,I tried loading extension library it loads but only some controls works and some are not.
For example I have added "dialog box,application-layout" this works with no issue but, when I add name picker and value picker is shows `Unhandled exception`.
To be more clear,
when I add name-picker and value picker without any values it looks perfectly working as in image.
[image: Extlib works with no data values]

Now when I add values in name picker or value picker or accordian is shows the error,
[image: Extlib doesn't works when added data values]

```
  <xe:namePicker id="namePicker2" for="members"
                dialogTitle="Teilnehmer auswählen">

                <xe:this.dataProvider>
                    <xe:namePickerAggregator>
                        <xe:this.dataProviders>
                            <xe:dominoNABNamePicker
                                addressBookSel="all"       nameList="peopleAndGroups"
                                groups="true">
                                <xe:this.addressBookDb><![CDATA[#  {javascript:var  nab:NotesDatabase=session.getDatabase(database.getServer(),"names.nsf");
      return  database.getServer() + "!!" + nab.getFilePath();}]]>    </xe:this.addressBookDb>
                            </xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
                        </xe:this.dataProviders>
                    </xe:namePickerAggregator>
                </xe:this.dataProvider>
            </xe:namePicker>
```

Comment: Are you using DDE local preview to test this or are you testing on a server?

Comment: I am testing it on server

Comment: You should install 8.5 version of ExtLib on your 8.5 Domino http://extlib.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Extension%20Library/releases/56832E9BD6A0615186257B4300349C59#

Comment: There is an another machine in which I have server 8.5,and I have installed 9.0 extension library and in that machine it works perfectly fine,I cant able get any thing where I am doing a mistake,It would be very helpful if I get a full and clear step by step guide to install extension library both on designer and server.

Comment: Now I have removed the domino designer version 9 and installed back everything to 8.5, even re-installed the extension library again, but having the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension Library relies on code available in the underlying XPages-related classes installed with the server. So if you install a ...9.0.1 version of Extension Library on an earlier server version, it will not be able to run properly. Always ensure the Extension Library version is appropriate for the server and bear in mind some functionality will not be available (so you won't be able to use `deviceBean`, some mobile components or the Bootstrap functionality included in more recentl versions of Extension Library.

I would still encourage you to use the latest Domino Designer, for better stability and tooling options. You can still have a 9.0.1 version of Extension Library installed, as far as I know. Designer just picks up tooling and doesn't includes Extension Library source code in the compiled NSF, so there's no conflict. An 8.5.3 version of Extension Library may not even install on a 9.0.1 client, I haven't tried.

On Xsp Properties, General tab, setting "Minimum Supported Release" to 8.5.3 will ensure it still compiles against the 8.5.3 limitations, which should ensure you don't accidentally use properties or functions that didn't exist until after 8.5.3.